# K-theory of l-adic sheaves of a curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology, etale-cohomology

I am trying to understand if there is a good notion of a $K$-theory attached to the etale topology on a nice scheme $X$ (say smooth projective goem connected curve over a finite field is enough for me)?

I am aware of the etale algebraic K-theory, which is an etale sheafification of the algebraic K-theory presheaf, and I think it is not the same as $K$-specturm of the exact category of $l$-adic sheaves on X.

Comment: What is the category of l-adic sheaves? If you are not careful, there might be an Eilenberg swindle.